# Can't get regex captured group working in Ruby on Rails method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, expression, gsub

I need to parse and replace text using gsub and a regular expression.  A simplified example appears below where I'm saving one of the captured groups -- \3 -- for use in my replacement string.

```
my_map.gsub(/(\shref=)(\")(\d+), ' href="/created_path/' + '\3' + '" ' + ' title="' + AnotherObject.find('\3')'"')
```

In the first use of the captured value, I'm simply displaying it to build the new path. In the second example, I am calling a find with the captured value.  The second example will not work.

I've tried various ways of escaping the value ("\3", ''\3'', etc) and even built a method to test displaying the value (works) or using the value in a method (doesn't work).

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the block form of [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) and replace your `\3` references with `$3` globals:

```
my_map.gsub(/(\shref=)(\")(\d+)/) { %Q{ href="/created_path/#{$3}" title="#{AnotherObject.find($3)"} }
```

I also switched to `%Q{}` for quoting to avoid the confusing quote mixing and concatenation.

The second argument in the replacement-string form of `gsub` (i.e. the version of `gsub` that you're trying to use) will be evaluated and concatenated **before** `gsub` is called and **before **the `\3` value is available so it won't work.

As an aside, is there a method you should be calling on what `AnotherObject.find($3)` returns?

Comment: This worked perfectly,mu. And yes, I am calling another method, but didn't include it here for simplicity.  Thank you!